Finding radius of horizon

If B (observer height, 40,000-feet) and C (distance from observer to horizon, 245-miles) are known then how do I solve for Z (radius of the horizon)?
The angle of B-C is 86.46-degrees so the angle of C-Z is 3.54-degrees if that helps.

You're probably getting downvotes because this is just barely a GIS question, and should maybe go to the Mathematics stack exchange site as a geometry question, even though the question is geographically based. But its very bad form for those people to downvote and not explain why.

It will be the distance C times the cosine of the angle at CZ. As you have calculated this is 90 degrees minus the angle at B-C because its a right angled triangle.
Hence Z = 245 * cos(86.46 degrees).
In R, converting to radians for cosine function:
> 245* cos(86.46 * pi/180)
[1] 15.12761

So 15.1 miles.
Note that the sine of one angle of a right-angle triangle is the same as the cosine of the other side (at least for triangles like this), so you can do:
> 245 * sin(3.54 * pi/180)
[1] 15.12761


I flipped the angle values for B-C and C-Z. The horizon is 3.54-degrees below the observer's los so that angle should be 86.46. With the appropriate angles it looks like Z would be 244.5-miles long.
Thank you for answering another question so understandably.

One formula is:
Horizon radius = Horizon distance * (r / (r+h))
r = radius of Earth, 3,959-miles
h = height of observer, 7.5758-miles
I.E.
245 * (3,959 / (3,959 + 7.5758))
245 * (3,959 / 3,966.5758)
245 * 0.99809
244.53-mile horizon radius
